# Как создать меню на kivy

Tags: python, gui, kivy

Камрады подскажите как создать меню на kivy. Пытаюсь использовать kivy.uix.actionbar. Создаю объект ActionBar, привязываю к главному окну, на котором появляется область меню. Дальше по идее по цепочке привязываются ActionView и ActionButton. Но при попытке привязать ActionView получаю ошибку: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'. Код ниже. Как победить эту напасть?
P.S. рекомендации использовать kv language не принимаются)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionBar
from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionView
from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionButton

class Container(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Container, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.menu()

    def menu(self):
        menu = ActionBar()
        aw = ActionView()
        #bt = ActionButton()
        menu.add_widget(aw)
        #aw.add_widget(bt)
        self.add_widget(menu)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Container()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось следующим: ActionView должно обязательно содержать экземпляр ActionPrevious, а затем все остальное, т.е. все свелось к добавлению трех строчек:

```
...
from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionPrevious
...
class Container(BoxLayout):
...
def menu(self):
...
action_previous = ActionPrevious(title='Title')
aw.add_widget(action_previous)
...
```